# Notation for some simple operator

Tags: functional-analysis, notation

Let $X$ a functional space space (I mean a space whose elements are functions). Let $f \in X$. Say I define these two operator (argument scaling and argument translation as follows)

$S_\alpha$ is a scaling operator means that $$\forall f \in X, S_\alpha f = g, g(x) = f(\alpha x).$$

$T_{x_0}$ is a translation operator means that

$$ \forall f \in X, T_{x_0} f = g, g(x) = f(x - x_0).$$

I think that notation is correct so far. Would be correct to write

$$
\begin{array}{l}
S_{\alpha} f = f(\alpha x) \\
T_{x_0} f = f(x - x_0)
\end{array}
$$

Or shall I write something like

$$
\begin{array}{l}
\left(S_{\alpha} f \right)(x) = f(\alpha x) \\
\left(T_{x_0} f \right)(x) = f(x - x_0)
\end{array}
$$

Also for the derivative

$$
\frac{d}{dx} f = f^{(1)}(x)
$$

or

$$
\left(\frac{d}{dx} f\right)(x) = f^{(1)}(x)
$$

(Maybe the last one can sound silly, but sometimes I'm puzzled in the meanings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$S_\alpha f$ is a function. It is defined by the expression for its values at an arbitrary $x$, namely $(S_\alpha f)(x) = f(\alpha x)$. The function $S_\alpha f$ should not be confused with $(S_\alpha f)(x)$, which is merely its value at $x$. You argue similarly for the correct notation in all the other definitions.

It's no different from the distinction we make with any other function and its values. For example, the exponential function $\exp:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is not the same as $\exp(x), x\in\mathbb{R}$: the first is a function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, the second is just an element of $\mathbb{R}$ (provided that $x$ is given). The tendency to identify the *function* $\exp$ with its *values* $\exp(x)$ is merely an abuse of notation.

Comment: So the correct notation is always $(Af)(x) = g(x)$, right? How about the derivative instead? I mean it confuse me when I want to highlight the variable I use for the derivation and the argument, isn't $\left( \frac{d}{dx}f \right)(x) = f^{(1)}(x)$ a bit cumbersome? Maybe in this case I could use $(Df)(x) = f^{(1)}(x)$, but what about partial differentiation, in that case I need to specify the derivation variable.

Comment: @user8469759 The derivative is the same, the important thing is to distinguish between the function $\frac{df}{dx}$ and its values $\frac{df}{dx}(x)$. As for what notation you use for partial derivatives, I've seen several notations, especially in the study of elliptic and parabolic PDEs where mixed partials are commonplace. Examples: $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j} = D_iD_j f = D_{ij}f = \partial_{x_i}\partial_{x_j}f = \partial_{ij}f$. For derivatives in single-variable calculus, we do of course have prime or dot notation: $\frac{df}{dx} = f' = \dot{f}$, etc.